# Wordpress custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: php, html

So I have a custom post type called `Video` and a taxonomy called `category` that I use to group videos togheter, so I want to list them like this:

```
Taxonomy NAME 1
VIDEO 1
VODEO 2

Taxonomy NAME 2
Video 1
Video 2
```

So I tried something but it doesn't work, the problem is that for each video I also display the taxonomy name like this:

```
Taxonomy Name 1
Video 1
Taxonomy Name 1
Video 2
```

So this is not what I want, mabe you guys can figure it out, what I do wrong:

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Video');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $fg = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'category'); ?>
        <?php foreach($fg as $term): ?>
                <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php
                        $posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'Video', 'category' => $term->name) );
                        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If someone can help please do it :( I can't get this

Comment: I hope so... :( 10x

Comment: Store the current taxonomy name in a variable, during every iteration compare the new name and the old name, if different, echo the taxonomy name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Anand's comment, something like this should work.

```
<?php get_header();?>

<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Video');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    $old_term = null;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ):
        $loop->the_post();
        $fg = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'category');
        foreach($fg as $term):
            if ( $old_term === null || $old_term != $term ):
                $old_term = $term;
?>
                <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
<?php
            endif;

            $posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'Video', 'category' => $term->name) );
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
                the_post_thumbnail();
?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
            endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata();
        endforeach;
    endwhile;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```